# Updating record in Database using Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am trying to update a record in Database using Django but it adds the same record again. How i can fix it? code is given below.

```
def update(request, id):
    book = tblbook.objects.get(id=id)
    form = tblbook(BookID = book.BookID, BookName=book.BookName, Genre=book.Genre,Price=book.Price) 
    form.save()
    return redirect("/show")
```

Answer (score 0):

your object is in book, as you have used get() method
now should do something like this

```
object_name.column_name = "Your value that you want to save"
```

accotding to your snippet it would be like this

```
book.BookID = "1"
book.BookName = "Any book name"
book.Genre = "Any genre"
book.Price = "Price of the book"
book.save()
```

You can also use update() method with filter() method, and it would look something like this

```
book = tblbook.objects.filter(id=id).update(BookID = "123", BookName="Any book name", Genre= "any genre", Price="price")
```

Comment: how i can get this data from form ?

Comment: the data from form will be in your request object.
So, you can do 
object_name.column_name = request.data["name key in your input field in your from "]

ex: book.BookID = request.data['book_name']
and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inserting new record to DB.
Suppose you want to update the book name, then below code might help-

```
book = tblbook.objects.get(id=id)
 
book.BookName = "some book name"

book.save()
```

similarly, you can update other fields as well

Comment: i got your point but i don't want to insert the values manually, i am trying to get the data from form

Comment: @Naumankhan, you can get the value from form such as-

request.POST.get(<name of the field>)